# Is there a certain strategy for "bomb jumping" in Metroid: Zero Mission?

Tags: metroid-zero-mission

In Metroid: Zero Mission, I am trying to get the Varia suit. I cannot time the bombs correctly to jump up to the first ledge; is there any strategy to doing this?

Comment: It often takes me half a dozen tries to get the bomb jump timing right, and that is only for simple jumps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the Varia Suit, you'll need the Spring Ball upgrade, which is a feature of the High Jump boots.  Do you have the High Jump boots yet?

This video might be informative:

At about :30 in he gets the High Jump Boots, and then at 5:30 he gets the Varia suit upgrade.

You can sequence break and get the Varia suit early.  If that's what you're going for, consult this video:

This requires some crazy timing with the bomb jumps though, so you might just stick to getting the High Jump boots instead.

In general, the timing of a bomb jump is to place a bomb, wait until the bomb is about to explode, and then place another.  At about 75% of your maximum height from the first bomb's explosion, place a third.  you'll fall back down, where the second bomb will explode, and then take you just above the third bomb, which will explode and take you higher.  Repeating this can get you to previously inaccessible areas, if your timing is juuuust right.

Comment: Hmm, I saw a video of a guy doing it using only bombs, and no Hi Jump Suit. That's what I'm interested in, but this is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahnax I actually added that to the answer in a quick edit after I posted.  There are several youtube videos for this, search for "youtube varia suit zero mission early" if you'd like more examples.